# How to increase the download speed when downloading via HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, download, httpurlconnection

I am downloading a ***.rar** file from my webserver using `HttpURLConnection`.
I have added some *temporary* lines of code to roughly measure (it was pretty inaccurate) the download speed when running the download via Java/`HttpURLConnection`. The download speed was fluctuating somewhere between 400kb/s and 2mb/s, approximately.

Downloading the same file through my browser (Mozilla FireFox) I get the full 12.5mb/s that my webserver supports. Using FireFox I download the file in about 6 seconds, whereas the Java code downloads the file in 12-30 seconds.

Here is a cleaned-up snippet of the code I am testing with, just to illustrate the approach of trying to download the file.

```
[...]

httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(downloadURL)).openConnection();
httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

[...]

try (InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream(); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)) {       

    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

[...]
```

I assume there is a bottleneck somewhere within this piece of code that I can't get ahold of.

How do I maximize the download speed?

Comment: Just to make it clear, are we talking 12.5MByte/s or 12.5Mbit/s?

Comment: Pardon, 12.5 megabyte/s (100Mbit).

Comment: I'd try increasing the 4k buffer to say 256k. A 4k buffer would need to be filled ~3000 times per seconds to fill your link which may be  bottleneck.

Comment: That really helped! Thank you very much, now I'm just 1-2 seconds behind the FireFox download (which I assume is due to I/O output within the while().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the buffer size. Increasing buffer size from `byte[4096]` to `byte[256000]` increased the download speed significantly. Furthermore I reduced I/O operations within the `while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)` loop, which contained a progress bar update, by making it run in its own thread.

Credits go to @Joachim Isaksson who pointed the buffer-bottleneck out in the comments above.